# Firefox SDK Add-on - How to start

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've already develop a little Firefox Extension using XUL and i would like to re-write it better using the new Firefox Add-On SDK.

Looking on web (and in Mozilla Dev Center) i havent found a guide/tutorial that explain from a starting point to the end. All guides describe some component in a standalone way, there are not full examples from the First line of code, to the end.

Adding on this, each "tutorial" in Mozilla Dev Center have some warning that say "this tutorial is deprecated" and so on.

So, there is a clean starting point to lear Firefox Add-On using SDK ?

Comment: This is an excellent guide to create your first addon within 15minutes (including install time of node.js/npm) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29

Comment: yes i've already read it and tested :) But this is a little short, hope to find more "advanced" guide. In my case, my "old" XUL was a toolbar and i've seen that with SDK this can be done with html file and communicate between main.js and this file. I'm trying to search something but without a reference point, its really difficult to unserstand if the current implementation is "the right" way. I think there are a lot of confusion around Firefox Extensions.

Answer (score 0):

For toolbars specifically, there is a [toolbar API example](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/tree/master/examples/toolbar-api) provided with the Addon SDK source on github.